# Importing Mapbox tiles to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, tiles, mapbox, wmts

I would like to use a basemap from the Ancient World Mapping Centre, available as maptiles via Mapbox, as basemap in my ArcMap desktop version 10.2.2.

I tried to import it as a new WMTS server with the following url:

`http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/isawnyu.map-knmctlkh/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE`

I replaced the 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE' by my token from Mapbox, but ArcMap did not want to create the WMTS.

I tried it in QGIS using the Tile Layer Plugin and everything worked perfect.

I prefer working with ArcMap, so I would like to know how I can import these tiles from Mapbox in my ArcMap desktop.

Comment: Try ArcBrutile extension (http://arcbrutile.codeplex.com/) will load the tiled maps into ArcGIS Desktop

Comment: I tried to add a TMS Provider in ArcBrutile, but received the message 'Could not download document'. The url I used must be correct since it worked in QGIS.

Comment: You can try ArcQMS https://qms.nextgis.com/about . Using QuickMapServices  will allow to use same tiles in QGIS, NextGIS Mobile, NextGIS Web and ArcGIS. It must be noted, that private QuickMapServices resources in plans, so now if you publish you key it became public.